Flutter Open Specific page upon Notification Click
Iam using oneSignal and want to navigate to a specific page in my app when clicking on the recived notification

the problem the code can't find context
this probably from the fact that iam declaring the listner in the wrong place
the Code Snippet :

OneSignal.Notifications.addClickListener((event) async {
       notificationAction = event.notification.additionalData!["id"];


        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => isLoggedIn(widget.token) ? TaskDetailsPage(
              jsonToken: widget.token!,
              taskId: notificationAction!,
              fromNotification: true,
            ) :LoginPage(taskId: notificationAction),
          ),
        );
    });

first what is the best place to define this listner:

declared it in main() function and AppClass initState Function() -> both didn't Work
-> Context Problem
Second Tried Using NavigationKey
can't seem to make it work cause i still need to declare the listner in the right place


I found this solution of how you can avoid using context for navigation:
Essentialy you need to:

Create a global variable which will hold NavigatorState.

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();


Pass this new variable to your App instance. Will use MaterialApp as example, but it will work for CupertinoApp too:

MaterialApp(
  ...
  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  ...
);


Use navigatorKey.currentState instead Navigator.of(context) wherever you want. Here, navigatorKey being global variable helping us, because it will be available anywhere in your code.

navigatorKey.currentState?.push(...)

P.S. Generally, I do not think that using global variable or GlobalKey is good idea, because Flutter Framework itself gave us BuildContext object and it implies to be right choice in every situation, where you need to pass/get contextual-aware data. But in your case, as context is unavailable, I think it is OK to use some globals :)
That said, I think that you should stick to recommended way of registering listeners from OneSignal example app: register it in initState() method.
